# Drupal Isn't Finding My CSS

Tags: theming, .info

My stylesheet is mentioned in my .info file, but it's not adding it to the page source and using it. The only style I have in *Styles.css* is `body {background:#444}`. I've tried clearing the site's cache as well as my browser's. CSS compression is off. Any ideas?

It's a theme I made from scratch.

info file:

```
name = PBmedia 14
description = The Site Theme
core = 7.x
engine = phptemplate



; Regions
; --------------------------------
regions[header] = Header
regions[content] = Content
regions[footer] = Footer



; Stylesheets
; --------------------------------
stylesheets[all] [] = html5reset-1.6.1.css
stylesheets[all] [] = styles.css
```

html.tpl.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html />


<head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
</head>
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable"><?php print t('Skip to main content'); ?></a>
  </div>
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

page.tpl.php

```
<div id="page-wrapper"><div id="page">

<header id="header">

  <?php if ($main_menu): ?>
  <nav id="navigation">
    <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix')), 'heading' => t(''))); ?>
  </nav><!-- #navigation -->
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
</header> <!-- #header -->





<?php print $messages; ?>

<div id="main-wrapper"><div id="main" class="clearfix">

  <div id="content">
  <div class="section">

    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
    <?php if ($title): ?><h1 class="title" id="page-title"><?php print $title; ?></h1><?php endif; ?>
    <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
    <?php if ($tabs): ?><div class="tabs"><?php print render($tabs); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
    <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
    <?php if ($action_links): ?><ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul><?php endif; ?>
    <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
    <?php print $feed_icons; ?>
  </div><!-- /.section -->
  </div> <!-- /#content -->


</div></div> <!-- /#main, /#main-wrapper -->

<footer id="footer">
  <?php print render($page['footer']); ?>
</footer><!-- #footer -->

</div></div> <!-- /#page, /#page-wrapper -->
```

Comment: Can you give more information on your theme's configuration?

Comment: If you are actually saying `stylesheet[all][]....` that is probably the problem because it should be `stylesheets[all][]....` eg plural

Comment: Ah right! I made them plural, cleared the caches and no change...

Comment: Is styles.css in the root of the theme, or is it in a CSS folder?

Comment: It's in the root.

Comment: Is that little ?> at the top of html.tpl.php a typo?

Comment: Yeah... It had the default page comments.

Comment: In your code above you have an extra space in between `stylesheets[all]` and `[]`.

Comment: The spaces solved it Adam!! Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

There should not be a space after "[all]" ...
Change:
`stylesheets[all] [] = styles.css`
to:
`stylesheets[all][] = styles.css`